# задать значение последнего символа из QTextEdit в char переменную

Tags: c++, qt

Как задать значение последнего символа из QTextEdit в char переменную?

Answer (score 3):

Для начала нужно взять текст - это toPlainText(). Оно возвратит QString. а у него уже взять back() - это как раз последний символ. Да, можно написать прям так `QChar c = edit.toPlainText().back();`, но я бы проверял, что там есть хотя бы один символ.

Answer (score 2):

Можете попробовать вот так `Qchar text = textCursor().block().text();`

Comment: что то мне кажется, что это будет возвращать символ под курсором, а не последний.

Comment: @KoVadim ну как правило, при наборе текста, курсор остаётся перед последним символом